# Referencing Stylesheet when sending email in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio-2010

I am dealing with a situation where I should change the font of a HTML body in C sharp using a stylesheet.

I have added a stylesheet to my project with name Stylesheet1.css which contains the code to change the font of a HTML body.

```
body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

I need to reference this stylesheet in source code, where I am processing the HTML body.
I am processing the HTML body as follows.

```
if(some condition)
{
 mail.HTMLBody= ? ? ? ? ;
}
```

I need to reference the stylesheet in this part. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use external stylesheets for emails. As alot of email clients do not support it.

See  http://groundwire.org/support/articles/css-and-email-newsletters

and
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssemail/

As some clients like hotmail remove the 'body' tag all togeather so your example in your question will not work. So you can instead wrap your email in a DIV  and use inline styles so you get best support for all email clients.

A list of what is supported by which client is here http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Style_In_Email

**Edit**

You should be able to set the font-size like this

```
<div style="font-size:10px;">
     your email content here
       <p style="font-size:14px;">
           some bigger text
       </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use div how can I add div to the HTML body just to change the font and font size?

Comment: I too agree with this. The problem with my present HTML is, I am not able to get the font size of 10.5, I am able to get only font size as 10 even if I increase the size to 4 or 5..How can I rectify this problem.

Comment: @thinkcool I am not sure what you mean by 10.5 font to increase to 4 or 5?   you mean you want some fonts 10px  and other sections 14px?
See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks..But I was asking about HTML is not giving the equivalent font size 10.5 when set to size 3 or 4 in the body. This was my problem. I am modifying the contents of the body like this

Comment: string Text = "<html><div basefont size=4 font face= consolas><body>" + mailItem.HTMLBody + "</font></body></div></html>"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daveo's answer - you are best off embedding styles directly rather than linking out to an external CSS

There is a very, very extensive matrix of styles & features that are and aren't supported by the popular email apps (outlook/gmail/yahoo mail/etc) at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I too agree with this. The problem with my present HTML is, I am not able to get the font size of 10.5, I am able to get only font size as 10 even if I increase the size to 4 or 5..How can I rectify this problem..

Comment: From your comment above, it looks like you are trying to use basefont on the div.  Don't do that.

Instead, specify the font-size on EVERY paragraph or span.

eg
     <p style='font-size:10.5px'>some text</p>

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ is a really good starting point for getting html and css right in emails.